# Get the windows LogOff Time?

Tags: java

I want to get the windows **shutdown/logoff time** by using `java.I` had tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());
```

I ran this code,I didn't get shutdown time.

Comment: You expect JVM shutdown to return you the windows logoff time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) is very clear of the method usage.

It says:

> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.

That means the JVM, not the underlying OS.

You should consider C++ or reading the Windows event log for your requirement.